# Difference between \framebox{$$} and \boxed{}

Tags: boxes, framed

I want to put an equation in a frame box. Is it the same that if I create a framed text box environment first then put the equation inside or use the environment `\boxed{}`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\framebox{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}

$\boxed{a^2+b^2=c^2}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Package `amsmath` defines `\boxed`:

```
\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
```

`\framebox` and `\fbox` are just different interfaces for the same internal `\@frameb@x`, which actually makes the box. `\framebox` has more options.

Thus, the main difference between `\framebox{$...$}` and `$\boxed{...}$` is that `\boxed` sets `\displaystyle`, whereas it had to be done manually in the former variant: `\framebox{$\displaystyle ...$}`.

Another difference appears, if `\mathsurround` is not zero. This space is set, when TeX enters and leaves inline math mode. It is intended as separation of math from the surrounding text. Inside the box it does not make sense and `\boxed` removes it by setting `\mathsurround` to zero by `\m@th`.

A test file, which illustrates the differences:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\vs}{\mathrel{\text{vs.}}}
  \begin{align*}
    \text{\ttfamily\string\framebox\{\$\dots\$\}} &\vs
    \text{\ttfamily\string\boxed\{\dots\}}
    \\
    \framebox{$\frac{123}{456}$} &\vs \boxed{\frac{123}{456}}
    \\
    \setlength{\mathsurround}{1em}\framebox{$X$} &\vs
    \setlength{\mathsurround}{1em}\boxed{X}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A simulation of `\boxed` would be:

```
\framebox{%
  \setlength{\mathsurround}{0pt}%
  $\displaystyle ...$%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply! By the way, would you please tell me where I can find the definition of `\boxed`?

Comment: @ZhangZe `kpsewhich amsmath.sty` (or locate the package file `amsmath.sty` by means of the OS), then line 307 (in version 2013/01/14 v2.14).

Comment: Okay. Gotta it!

Answer (score 4):

For such questions I just load the package `lua-visual-debug`. You can see clearly that they are both the same:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
\blindtext  

\framebox{$\displaystyle a^2+b^2=c^2$} % displaystyle needed here, as it is set in \boxed by default. It just changes the horizontal spacing of the powers a bit. 

$\boxed{a^2+b^2=c^2}$

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

The boxing is equal speaking of spacing and aligning. Therefore, both approaches are similar. For the syntactical equivalence, see Heiko's answer.