# How to frame inline text with a box?

Tags: tcolorbox, inline

I am trying to frame a text inline like this:

[image]

The text above is from the book Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces from Kristopher Tapp.

As requested by some users, some code to edit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    Bla bla bla.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
    Bla bla bla bla.

    (1) \(\implies\) (2) Bla bla bla.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit your question to include some code please that we can then edit, as it stands you want us to write the entire code

Comment: Just did @JamesT

Comment: You should keep math expressions in math env. that is `(1) \(\implies (2)\)` should be `\((1) \implies (2)\)`. One reason is font used in math could be different and you might end up in oddly typeset expressions. As to your boxes: use `\fbox{}` to box words and ininline maths or `\boxed{}` (`amsmath`) in display math env. (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253297/31283) for details).

Comment: Thank. It was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        Bla bla bla.
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{proof}
        Bla bla bla bla.
        
        \fbox{(1) \(\implies (2)\)} Bla bla bla.
    \end{proof}
    
\end{document}
```